# How to get information of list of clases with Parallel?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem when I use `Parallel.ForEach` in VB.net, I have a list of entities and I receive `IEnumerable` of objects (`myClass`). 
I want to get some information in each iteration of the objects received but the program doesn't work when I create the object inside of the parallel.foreach 
this is my code:

```
Friend Sub ChanceSomething(items As IEnumerable(Of Model.myClass))
    Dim entity As New Model.myEntity
    Dim entities = Me.EntitiesList()        ' this is an IEnumerable(of myEntity), database query

    Parallel.ForEach(items, Sub(item as Model.myClass)
        ' select the entity with the same id's
        entity = entities.Where(Function(i) i.IdEntityClient = item.IdClient).FirstOrDefault()
        item.OwnerName = entity.OwnerName
        item.Id = entity.Id    

            End Sub)
End Sub
```

Other way is something like this:
The`parallel.ForEach` doesn't have the object and I consult the DB twice (I don't like it, I believe that it is inefficient) and I get the necessary data in the same query.
This way works but I need to do something like the First method.

```
Friend Sub ChanceSomething(items As IEnumerable(Of Model.myClass))

    Dim entities = Me.EntitiesList()        ' this is an IEnumerable(of myEntity)

    Parallel.ForEach(items, Sub(item as Model.myClass)
        item.OwnerName = entities.Where(Function(i) i.IdEntityClient = item.IdClient).Select(Function(result) result.OwnerName).FirstOrDefault()
        item.Id = entities.Where(Function(i) i.IdEntityClient = item.IdClient).Select(Function(result) result.Id).FirstOrDefault()    

            End Sub)
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: "but the program doesn't work" - how so?  In the first code block you are re-using the `entity` variable for each item, which seems like it would cause issues - perhaps try `Dim`ming it inside the lambda?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mark, in the first block of code I need to asign the object of entities.Where(Function(i) i.IdEntityClient = item.IdClient).FirstOrDefault() and put him in the variable "entity", then I have to take the values of some atributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are running into issues because the `entity` variable is shared between the iterations of the `ForEach` loop.  Try changing the scope of the `entity` variable, so there is a separate instance for each `item`:

```
Friend Sub ChanceSomething(items As IEnumerable(Of Model.myClass))
    Dim entities = Me.EntitiesList()        ' this is an IEnumerable(of myEntity), database query
    Parallel.ForEach(items, Sub(item as Model.myClass)
        ' select the entity with the same id's
        Dim entity As Model.myEntity = entities.Where(Function(i) i.IdEntityClient = item.IdClient).FirstOrDefault()
        item.OwnerName = entity.OwnerName
        item.Id = entity.Id    
    End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: I did it, but the result is the same, I'll keep trying, thanks.

Comment: I found the problem, it's necessary to evaluate the variable entity, it can't be "Nothing" and in some cases this can happen because the list "entities" could have entities that don't match with the object in the iteration.

Comment: If entidad IsNot Nothing Then 
    item.OwnerName = entity.OwnerName
    item.Id = entity.Id    
   end if